# What is HCC? Is it a Virus?

Tags: virus

What is HCC? Is it a Virus? I found this files (links below) and I want to know what they really are!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea off the top of my head but a bit of a Google led me to this possibility:

1. Common instances of the file hcc.exe - [Click me](http://processchecker.com/file/hcc.exe.html)
2. It looks like your employer might not have evey faith in your computer usage! - [Click me](http://extraspy.net/)

Comment: And don't worry, I found this files in a school computer, I just wanted to be sure.